# Cannot save data in custom field on external object

Tags: lightning-connect, externalobjects

I have an external object that is coming from a heroku postgres database. I have managed to successfully import the data but not all of the fields have been imported. There is a field on the postgres table that is an enum type. This field was not imported and I cannot find any documentation specifically stating what fields can and cannot be imported.

Since the enum field could not be imported I decided to make a custom field equivalent of the same field. Problem is, the data that I enter into the picklist does not get saved and disappears from the page on save. I am following this documentation and it sounds like I should be able to add an unrestricted picklist without any problems, but it is just not working out(https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.odata_considerations_picklist.htm&type=5).
Any ideas?

Comment: Supported: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-external-objects#supported-data-types : _If you enable a table or view that has an unsupported data type, the unsupported field will not be included in results._

Comment: I have come to terms with that. Do you have any idea why when I add any custom fields to the external object from salesforce none of the data gets saved?